# How to create a list of chat based on last sent

Tags: mysql, sql

i have a table for chat like this

[image]

i want to create a list based on last sent messages of a user to admin. what should be the mysql query for this.

expected result :

```
8 rafee hi
7 asdf  asfsh
```

if admin sent last to a user then it is also should be in the message list.
for example if admin sent asdf a message then the result should be

```
9 asdf  hello
8 rafee hi
```

please help...

Comment: Your requirement isn't clear. And please don't use images for sample data.

Answer (score -1):

You need to order the data fetched from the table you can do this by the following query.

```
SELECT * 
FROM `tableName` 
ORDER BY `timeStamp` DESC
```

Comment: it will return all messages